# How to change the language of "OK" button in gtk_message_dialog_new

Tags: c++, gtk

I'm drawing gtk dialogue box as shown below :

```
    GtkDialogFlags flags = GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT;
    GtkWidget *dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new (GTK_WINDOW(webkitBrowserWindow),
                                             flags,
                                             GTK_MESSAGE_INFO,
                                             GTK_BUTTONS_OK,
                                             "%s",message_data->str.str );
    //Setting min-width and min-height for popup.
    if(gtkWebView){
        gint minWidth = 0, minHeight = 0;
        gtk_widget_get_size_request (GTK_WIDGET(gtkWebView), &minWidth, &minHeight);
        gtk_widget_set_size_request (GTK_WIDGET(dialog), minWidth, minHeight);
    }
    gtk_widget_show(dialog);
    gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));
    gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);
    popupInProgress=false;
```

But i would like to change the language of text content and "OK" button as per system language, i have written an inbuilt function for language change which returns translated string, using which i'm able to update the language of text content of the dialogue box, but i'm not sure how to change the language of "OK" button.

Please suggest.

TIA.

Regards,

Lakshmikanth .G

Comment: This is a standard dialog, with default buttons. It already has all is needed for translation. Which language are you trying to use? Have you tried running your application with `LC_ALL=<language identifier> ./yourapplication`? Are the translations for the desired language installed?

Comment: No, i do not want to use other language identifiers, i would like to use my own language translation..and i want the similar thing to be done for QT dialog box with OK button. please suggest.

Comment: You misunderstood me. Either that GTK+ string is not translated in your language, or your run it with wrong locale settings, or the translations for your language are not installed. Telling us which language it is and its language identifier would help.

Comment: Here are the translations available for GTK+: https://l10n.gnome.org/module/gtk+/